# FCM Vs GCM? Why we need to migrate from GCM to FCM

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

Hello Friends I am new to this stackoverflow community, but have wide experience in developing code using various programming languages like android. Today I was implementing GCM with one of my application, I was facing some problem of delay in push notification message.  I was reading about it on goggle and found somewhere that some new service named **FCM** launched by google recently. I read various article or blog but did not find much information from there. I have some questions in mind,  pls give your views, all stackoverflowian  are heartily invited to give their suggestion.

- Why we need this FCM.
- FCM over GCM.
- Is GCM now depreciated. Are they going to stop all services & support
  of gcm.
- How to update my old applications from GCM to FCM.
- Can anyone show me the original link where google announced the FCM
  over GCM, because i did not found this originally posted google.

> Thank you All!
>
> Jordan Chaffins