# Android migration from GCM to oneSignal push notification

Tags: android, eclipse, google-cloud-messaging, onesignal

I have an Android project using GCM push notification, but my client wants me to migrate from GCM to oneSignal push notification. (negotiable)
The project is a bit old and developed using eclipse.
so my question; is it a good idea to change to oneSignal and what is the difference between GCM and oneSignal ? Better performance ? more features ? is it recommended to use it instead of GCM? Sorry I am an Android beginner and couldn't really find lots of information about oneSignal any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

OneSignal provides both an API, as well as marketing tools for notifications.

Unlike using the GCM/FCM APIs directly, with OneSignal you can target specific segments of users, schedule notifications, and monitor notification click through rate. OneSignal also provides an Android SDK which takes care of many technical implementation details.

Behind-the-scenes OneSignal then connects to GCM/FCM and sends notifications on behalf of your application.

Answer (score 2):

First, are you aware that [Eclipse is no longer officially supported](http://www.i-programmer.info/news/193-android/8733-google-drops-support-for-eclipse-its-all-android-studio-now.html) for Android Development. Using Eclipse may be preventing you to quickly creating apps and finding the necessary resources to build a project.

To migrate to the Android Studio from Eclipse just follow this [tutorial](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/migrate.html) from Google developers.

Now, for your question about GCM and onesignal, why don't you consider the [FCM](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/). The FCM is the new/upgrade version of the GCM. It inherits the reliable and scalable GCM infrastructure, plus new features! If you are integrating messaging in a new app, start with FCM. GCM users are strongly recommended to upgrade to FCM, in order to benefit from new FCM features today and in the future. And FCM is easy to use plus it simplifies client development. You no longer have to write your own registration or subscription retry logic

This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37452463/fcm-vs-gcm-why-we-need-to-migrate-from-gcm-to-fcm) will add you more information about FCM.

If you still want to migrate to [oneSignal](https://onesignal.com/webpush), then this [link](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs) will help you to know what is oneSignal and why you should use it.