# GCM --> FCM will push token ID gets changed

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have an app in Playstore with GCM and we retrieve pustoken ID for mass notification push.

After migrating to FCM and update app, will the push token ID gets changed?

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37678248/in-what-period-does-the-firebases-app-token-changes-and-how-to-manage-it and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37611731/will-fcm-token-change-periodically-like-gcm-registration-id

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FCM Vs GCM? Why we need to migrate from GCM to FCM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37452463/fcm-vs-gcm-why-we-need-to-migrate-from-gcm-to-fcm)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What happens to older clients when you migrate an app server from GCM to FCM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43016683/what-happens-to-older-clients-when-you-migrate-an-app-server-from-gcm-to-fcm)